# Jquery 1.7 and Jquery 1.8.3

Tags: jquery

I use Jquery 1.7 for slider and Jquery 1.8.3 for effect but these have problem together

```
$( "button" ).hover(function(e) {   
    $( ".support-part" ).toggle( 'slow' );
});
```

This code work in 1.8.3 but when it's work the slider does not work
And Now I want to know how we can use two versions together without any problem ??

Comment: I'm also confused why you need both jQuery's in this case, why wouldn't `1.8.3` be able to handle everything?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I have **no idea**. I agree with you.

Comment: I try to use 1.8.3 for both of them but the slider dose not worked

Comment: What are the errors coming up in the Console log?

Comment: I think the problem was how to Arrangement them because , Now I input 1.8.3 top of the <head> and now the slider is working with 1.8.3 but now the effect it does not Working  ;) so how can I fix it ? Where should I put the effect codes ? In bottom of the codes ? before </body> ? or in <head> ?

Answer (score 2):

If by "together" you mean loaded on the same page -- That is **not** a good idea.

Load one and use `noConflict()`, then load the other if you *really* want to use both.

```
<script src="jQuery1.7"></script>
<script> 
    $7 = $.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="jQuery1.8.3"></script>
```

Use `$7` for jQuery 1.7 and `$` for jQuery 1.8.3